# tag label align

Tags: html, label, alignment

I have this code:

```
<label for="filter_da" style="color: #ffffff;">Da</label>
   <input value=""  id="filter_da" name="filter_da" type="text" />
```

how can I align the label at the top of the input in css mode?

Comment: http://www.jsfiddle.net/NqazJ/ are they not alligned at the top? i dont get the question, do you want them to appear on top of eachother?

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="filter_da">Da</label> <br />
<input value=""  id="filter_da" name="filter_da" type="text" />
```

or

```
<div> <label for="filter_da">Da</label> </div>
<div><input value=""  id="filter_da" name="filter_da" type="text" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean?

```
label {display:block;}
```

by declaring label as block element, anything placed after it will occupy new line.

Hope that help :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the Label in Div tag and use style float:top.

If you want to use in css then write this in css class and embed the class in label.

```
.classTop
    {
     width:100%;height:10%; float: top;
    }
```